# Improper reflection in recursive ray tracer

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I'm implementing a recursive ray tracer with reflection. The ray tracer is currently reflecting areas that are in shadow, and I don't know why. The shadow aspect of the ray tracer works as expected when the reflective code is commented out, so I don't think that's the issue.

```
Vec Camera::shade(Vec accumulator,
                  Ray ray,
                  vector<Surface*>surfaces,
                  vector<Light*>lights,
                  int recursion_depth) {

if (recursion_depth == 0) return Vec(0,0,0);

double closestIntersection = numeric_limits<double>::max();
Surface* cs;
for(unsigned int i=0; i < surfaces.size(); i++){
    Surface* s = surfaces[i];

    double intersection = s->intersection(ray);

    if (intersection > EPSILON && intersection < closestIntersection) {
        closestIntersection = intersection;
        cs = s;
    }
}
if (closestIntersection < numeric_limits<double>::max()) {

    Point intersectionPoint = ray.origin + ray.dir*closestIntersection;
    Vec intersectionNormal = cs->calculateIntersectionNormal(intersectionPoint);

    Material materialToUse = cs->material;

    for (unsigned int j=0; j<lights.size(); j++) {

        Light* light = lights[j];

        Vec dirToLight = (light->origin - intersectionPoint).norm();
        Vec dirToCamera = (this->eye - intersectionPoint).norm();


        bool visible = true;
        for (unsigned int k=0; k<surfaces.size(); k++) {
            Surface* s = surfaces[k];

            double t = s->intersection(Ray(intersectionPoint, dirToLight));

            if (t > EPSILON && t < closestIntersection) {
                visible = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (visible) {
            accumulator = accumulator + this->color(dirToLight, intersectionNormal,
                                             intersectionPoint, dirToCamera, light, materialToUse);
        }

    }

    //Reflective ray
    //Vec r = d − 2(d · n)n
    if (materialToUse.isReflective()) {
        Vec d = ray.dir;
        Vec r_v = d-intersectionNormal*2*intersectionNormal.dot(d);
        Ray r(intersectionPoint+intersectionNormal*EPSILON, r_v);
        //km is the ideal specular component of the material, and mult is component-wise multiplication
        return this->shade(accumulator, r, surfaces, lights, recursion_depth--).mult(materialToUse.km);
    }
    else
        return accumulator;
}
else
    return accumulator;
}

Vec Camera::color(Vec dirToLight,
                  Vec intersectionNormal,
                  Point intersectionPoint,
                  Vec dirToCamera,
                  Light* light,
                  Material material) {

//kd I max(0, n · l) + ks I max(0, n · h)p

Vec I(light->r, light->g, light->b);
double dist = (intersectionPoint-light->origin).magnitude();
I = I/(dist*dist);

Vec h = (dirToLight + dirToCamera)/((dirToLight + dirToCamera).magnitude());

Vec kd = material.kd;
Vec ks = material.ks;

Vec diffuse = kd*I*fmax(0.0, intersectionNormal.dot(dirToLight));

Vec specular = ks*I*pow(fmax(0.0, intersectionNormal.dot(h)), material.r);

return diffuse+specular;

}
```

I've provided my output and the expected output. The lighting looks a bit different b/c mine was originally an .exr file and the other is a .png, but I've drawn arrows in my output where the surface should be reflecting shadows, but it's not.

[image: My output]

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Can you reduce the geometry in your example renders down to two or three objects and one light? It's a little hard to diagnose with the amount of complexity in the image.

Comment: Also, is one of the examples images supposed to be with "reflective code commented out", as you say? I ask because both appear to show reflections.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson  Both images were created with reflective code on. The top image is my output, and the bottom image is the expected output. (The only reason I mentioned commenting out the reflective code was to clarify that the shadow code works properly, so it is somehow the reflective code that is introducing the bug.)

Comment: OK. What initial value are you using for `recursion_depth`? Does the issue go away if you increase it?

Comment: `recursion_depth` is 20. Increased to 100, and it didn't go away.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check:

1. The visibility check in the inner `for` loop might be returning a false positive (i.e. it's calculating that all `surfaces[k]` are not closer to `lights[j]` than your intersection point, for some `j`). This would cause it to incorrectly add that `light[j]`'s contribution to your `accumulator`. This would result in missing shadows, but it ought to happen everywhere, including your top recursion level, whereas you're only seeing missing shadows in reflections.
2. There might an error in the `color()` method that's returning some wrong value that's then being incremented into `accumulator`. Although without seeing that code, it's hard to know for sure.
3. You're using postfix decrement on `recursion_depth` inside the `materialToUse.IsReflective()` check. Can you verify that the decremented value of `recursion_depth` is actually being passed to the `shade()` method call? (And if not, try changing to prefix decrement).

   ```
   return this->shade(... recursion_depth--)...
   ```

EDIT: Can you also verify that `recursion_depth` is just a parameter to the `shade()` method, i.e. that there isn't a global / static `recursion_depth` anywhere. Assuming that there isn't (and there shouldn't be), you can change the call above to

```
    return this->shade(... recursion_depth - 1)...
```

EDIT 2: A couple of other things to look at:

4. In `color()`, I don't understand why you're including the direction to the camera in your calculations. The color of intersections other than the first one, per pixel, ought to be independent of where the camera is. But I doubt that's the cause of this issue.
5. Verify that `return this->shade(accumulator, r, surfaces, lights, recursion_depth--).mult(materialToUse.km);` is doing the right thing with that matrix multiplication. Why are you multiplying by `materialToUse.km`?
6. Verify that `materialToUse.km` is constant per surface (i.e. it doesn't change over the geometry of the surface, the depth of iteration, or anything else).
7. Break up the statement `return this->shade(accumulator, r, surfaces, lights, recursion_depth--).mult(materialToUse.km);` into its component objects, so you can see the intermediate results in the debugger:

   ```
   Vec reflectedColor = this->shade(accumulator, r, surfaces, lights, recursion_depth - 1);
   Vec multipliedColor = reflectedColor.mult(materialToUse.km);
   return multipliedColor;
   ```
8. Determine the image (x, y) coordinates of one of your problematic pixels. Set a conditional breakpoint that's triggered when rendering that pixel, and then step through your `shade()` method. Assuming you pick the pixel pointed to by the bottom right arrow in your example image, you ought to see one recursion into `shade()`. Stepping through that the first recurse, you'll see that your code is incorrectly adding the light contribution from the floor, when it should be in shadow.

Comment: I'm skeptical that it would be #1 because as you mentioned there would be an issue on shadows as well. Plus, that `break` statement exits the `for` loop right away when it finds a surface closer than the `closestIntersection`.  The postfix decrement was not correct, so I switched to `recursion_depth-1`. But `recursion_depth` never hits 0, only 19. Could it be because the reflective ray hits a surface that's not reflective? Is this okay?

Comment: "But recursion_depth never hits 0, only 19." `recursion_depth` will only get decremented if you're hitting a reflective surface. If it's 18, that means your call stack is three deep (the current ray has hit 2 reflective surfaces consecutively, and you're considering the third surface, etc). Also, you might find that it makes more intuitive sense to count your iterations up instead of down, i.e. start at `0`, increment with every recurse, and change your base case to check against a `recursion_limit` (which you predefine as a global, = 20 or whatever).

Comment: That makes sense. Any last thoughts on what might be causing the issue now that i've included `color()`?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: I was not checking that the `t` should be less than the distance from the intersection to light position.

Instead of:

```
if (t > EPSILON && t < closestIntersection) {
    visible = false;
    break;
}
```

it should be:

```
if (t > EPSILON && t < max_t) {
    visible = false;
    break;
}
```

where `max_t` is

```
double max_t = dirToLight.magnitude();
```

before `dirToLight` has been normalized.

Comment: Were you able to observe this happening at the top recursion level? If not, I assume that's just an artifact of the way the geometry is distributed in your example?